# How to print to thermal printer from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print a QR code (or really just anything at this point) to a thermal printer via bluetooth from a Flutter app. I'm using [esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils) for generating the print command bytes and [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) for managing the bluetooth connections. I've successfully been able to connect to the printer, scan for the bluetooth services, and find the writable characteristic. Note - the UUIDs below are the UUIDs for the only actual writable characteristic on this particular printer (Phomemo M120).

```dart
connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    // listen for disconnection
    device.connectionState.listen((BluetoothConnectionState state) async {
      if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected) {
        // typically, start a periodic timer that tries to periodically reconnect.
        // Note: you must always re-discover services after disconnection!
        // TODO - do something
      }
    });

    // Connect to the device
    // Note: You should always call `connectionState.listen` before you call connect!
    await device.connect();
    _connectedDevice = device;

    // Yank the MTU
    _mtu = await device.mtu.first;

    // Note: You must call discoverServices after every connection!
    List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
    _services = services;

    services.forEach((service) async {
      // Reads all characteristics
      var characteristics = service.characteristics;
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
        print(c.toString());
        if (c.characteristicUuid.toString() ==
                "0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" &&
            service.serviceUuid.toString() ==
                "0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
          _characteristic = c;
        }
        // List<int> value = await c.read();
        // print(value);
      }
    });
  }
```

When I try to generate the bytes and print, the printer does react, it just feeds a couple of labels out without actually printing anything.

```
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, profile);
    List<int> bytes = [];

    bytes += generator.text("abc TEST 123");
    bytes += generator.qrcode('example.com');
    await _characteristic!.write(bytes, allowLongWrite: true);
```

I've also tried using TSPL commands, which according to manufacturer, this printer also supports. [Phomemo m120 manual](https://phomemo.com/pages/download-center-m120) (may have to scroll down a bit, but it claims to support ESC/POS/TSPL instruction sets.

```
List<int> printText(String text) {
    List<String> commands = [];

    // Set fixed label size
    commands.add('SIZE 40 mm,30 mm\n');

    // Clear the buffer
    commands.add('CLS\n');

    // Add text, we assume standard text properties
    commands.add('TEXT 10,10,"3",0,1,1,"$text"\n');

    // Print the label
    commands.add('PRINT 1\n');

    // END
    commands.add('END\n');

    // Convert commands to bytes
    List<int> bytes = commands
        .map((command) => command.codeUnits)
        .expand((codeUnit) => codeUnit)
        .toList();

    return bytes;
  }
```

But the same thing, the printer just feeds out a couple of labels without printing anything. I know the printer isn't faulty as using the manufacturer app, it does print successfully. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
bluetooth.writeBytes(utf8.encode("abc TEST 123"));
```

rather:

```
await _characteristic!.write(bytes, allowLongWrite: true);
```

Or with:

```
String string = "abc TEST 123";
bytes = string.codeUnits;
```

rather:

```
bytes += generator.text("abc TEST 123");
```

Make sure you are connected to your printer